# Schema has not been registered for model

Tags: javascript, node.js

hi whats wrong in my script, when I try to run it always says that Schema has not been registered for model

```js
var session = require('express-session');
var flash = require('connect-flash');
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

mongoose.Promise = global.Promise;

mongoos.connect('mongodb://localhost/csvUploads', {
  useMongoClient: true
});

require('./models/csvUpload');
```

This is my app.js and below is the model

```js
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var csvUploadsSchema = new Schema({
  jirakey: {
    type: String,
    required: 'Cannot be Left blank.'
  },
  status: {
    type: String,
    required: 'Cannot be Left blank.'
  },
  priority: {
    type: String,
    required: 'Cannot be Left blank.'
  },
  ...
})

module.exports = mongoose.model('csvUpload', csvUploadsSchema);
```

**My error message:**

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to `require` that file in `app.js` file to register your schema.

Something like `require('./path/to/model.js')` in your server file. And require it before connecting to db

Comment: I dont have a server.js do I need to make one? And where will I place it?

Comment: I mean whatever the name of your server file is. the file you run with `node`

Comment: @ReinardCarranceja your main file inshort

Comment: I already put require on my app.js still the error is showing up

Comment: I am saying to require in app.js. Instead require your app.js file in main file. you've written in your question that you've defined schemas in your `app.js` file. that's the file I am talking about. `require('./models/csvUpload');` is wrong I guess. It should be the path to the file where you defined schemas

Comment: the model is named csvUpload, can you tell me what the main file is cause I think the app.js is the main file

Comment: No. the snipped you pasted as first snippet in your code should be main file

Comment: yes that is the app.js, I check if the file path is correct and it is correct still getting that error message

Comment: Ohk. Sorry my bad. now try replacing `require('./models/csvUpload');` with `require('./models.js')` and write it after `var mongoose = require('mongoose');`

Comment: stil error, I have updated my post it shows the error message may be it can help you in resolving my problem

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const yourSchema = mongoose.Schema({
value: {
    type: String,
    required: true, 
    trim: true,
},
title: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
    trim: true,
},...

module.export = mongoose.model("NameModel", yourSchema, "collectionName");
```

Answer (score 0):

**Config File**

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
mongoose.connection.openUri(config.env.DB_URL, options, function(error){
    if(error){
        console.log(error);
        return;
    } else {
        console.log("connected");
    }
});
mongoose.Promise = global.Promise;
mongoose.set('debug', true);
```

**Model File**

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const debug = require('debug')('http')

const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const csvUploadsSchema = new Schema({
  jirakey: {
    type: String,
    required: 'Cannot be Left blank.'
  },
  status: {
    type: String,
    required: 'Cannot be Left blank.'
  },
  priority: {
    type: String,
    required: 'Cannot be Left blank.'
  }
})
module.exports = mongoose.model('csvUpload', csvUploadsSchema);
```